# Poor performance of multiple aggregations with windowing in Pandas

Tags: multithreading, performance, pandas, aggregation, windowing

I need to calculate in Pandas a lot of aggregations by Dataframe index and with taking in mind windowing by time (column MONTH). Something like:

```
# t is my DataFrame
grouped=t.groupby(t.index)

    def f(g):
        g1=g[g.MONTH<=1]
        g2=g[g.MONTH<=5]
        agrs=[]
        index=[]
        for c in cat_columns:
            index.append(c+'_EOP')
            agrs.append(g.iloc[0][c])
        for c in cont_columns:
            index.append(c+'_MEAN_2')
            mean2=g1[c].mean()
            agrs.append(mean2)
            index.append(c+'_MEAN_6')
            mean6=g2[c].mean()
            agrs.append(mean6)
            index.append(c+'_MEDIAN_2')
            agrs.append(g1[c].median())
            index.append(c+'_MEDIAN_6')
            agrs.append(g2[c].median())
            index.append(c+'_MIN_2')
            agrs.append(g1[c].min())
            index.append(c+'_MIN_6')
            agrs.append(g2[c].min())
            index.append(c+'_MAX_2')
            agrs.append(g1[c].max())
            index.append(c+'_MAX_6')
            agrs.append(g2[c].max())
            index.append(c+'_MEAN_CHNG')
            agrs.append((mean2-mean6)/mean6)
        return pd.Series(agrs, index=index)
    aggrs=grouped.apply(f)
```

I have 100-120 attributes in each list: cat_columns and cont_columns and about 1.5 million of rows.
The performance is very slow (I'm waiting already 15 hours). How to speed up it?

Probably there exactly two questions:
1. Can I speed up performance with tuning this code with use of Pandas only?
2. Is it possible to calculate the same aggregations in [Dask](http://dask.pydata.org/) (I read it is multi-core wrapper over Pandas)? I already tried to parallelize work with help of joblib. Something like (I also added cont_columns to the prototype of f):

```
def tt(grouped, cont_columns):
    return grouped.apply(f, cont_columns)
r = Parallel(n_jobs=4, verbose=True)([delayed(tt)(grouped, cont_columns[:16]),
                                 delayed(tt)(grouped, cont_columns[16:32]),
                                 delayed(tt)(grouped, cont_columns[32:48]),
                                  delayed(tt)(grouped, cont_columns[48:])]
                                 )
```

But got unlimited recursion error in Pandas groupby.

Pandas experts, please advise!

Thanks!

Sergey.

Comment: I would expect the calculation to be much faster if you can avoid the custom function and do the aggregation with buildin pandas commands. For example, you can create indicator variables for the two periods, then groupby index and the indicator variable at the same time and run aggregation functions on those groups. If it doesn't have to be in pandas and you want speed, put the data in a SQL db and aggregate using SQL commands.

Comment: It seems to be a lot of points of improvement. Can you give some lines of `t` to  see what can be done in your case ?

Comment: Alexander Baurer, B.M, thank you!  t - is just DataFrame with a lot of columns, so I not sure it can get some information. It is interesting to me if my approach generally speaking is right for making a lot of very custom aggregations in pandas. I understand that there are a lot of details influe the performance (like precompute something or not to use common index syntax for filtering..). Can presort on index help with speed? And the most interesting question: how my case can be parallelized?